# Application Insights Failover Architecture

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, disaster-recovery

We are designing an Azure based system that needs to be redundant and able to handle regional outage. We are using application insights for all logging. Is an Application Insights instance itself regionally distributed? or will we need to design our systems to store multiple application insights keys and switch over to backup if primary AI instance suffers a regional failure? I cannot fight any disaster recovery information on Application Insights service and best practices.

Comment: you can send logs to Log analytics and have multiple workspaces

Answer (score 0):

For App Insights a recommendation an App Insights per Instance of your application. Ideally an app hosted in East US will have associated App Insights in East US. Then can send to Log Analytics to query across multiple instances.

Comment: Should the Log Analytics workspace be in the same region as the app insights? We have East US and South US App Insights instances. Trying to determine if I should point both to the same workspace in East US or setup one in East US and one in South US

Comment: Depends. If multi regions are sending traffic to one workspace there could be an uptick in network costs. This is a design question too. If you were to assume Azure has a regional outage it could impact your application even if it isn't hosted in the impacted region as it could still have compenents that are impacted.